# Windows form's key down event

Tags: winforms, events, focus

I have 4 buttons with keydown events but only 1 button is working and that is the one with focus. How can i solve this so all button events can occur when i use keyboard no matter what control has focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the buttons to receive the `KeyDown` event, you should handle the event on their common parent window instead on the individual buttons. In order for that to work, you should also set the [Form.KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true`.